# two column document so in the first i have text and in the second pictures

Tags: two-column

I want to make a two column document such as in the first column there is text and in the second column pictures with examples for the text.
How can i do that?

Comment: you could utilize the `multicolumn` package for this

Comment: I would suggest one column with a large margin and \marginpar or \marginnote to place the graphics.

Comment: I have a problem with the second comment. When i use \includegraphics it doesn't fit the margin. Even when i use \textwidth. Is there something else i can do?

Comment: @thodoris as ulrike said, use `\marginpar{\includegraphics{...}}`

Comment: use  `\marginparwidth` for the width of the images

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Related: [To separate text column from figures column in every page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71508/objective-to-separate-text-column-from-figures-column-in-every-page/78413#78413)

Comment: The problem with the `multicolumn` package is that the default doesn't let you know whether you're on the left or right column, and when you switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

If you love the `tufte-handout` or `tufte-book` default style, these document classes are what you are looking for. It might be also a good option if you know how adapt this style to your own preferences, as in this "de-tufted" MWE. In other case, this has been already answered in the comments.

[image: MWE]

```
    \documentclass[nofonts,nols,justified]{tufte-handout} 
\usepackage{mwe} % for demo images
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcaptionfont{\itshape\sffamily}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{blue!80!black}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{blue!60!black}\thesection.}{.5em}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Lore ipsum}
\lipsum*[2] (See figure \ref{a}).

\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Some clever caption\label{a}}
\end{marginfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Na dui ligula (figure \ref{b})}
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Some clever caption\label{b}}
\end{marginfigure}
See figure \ref{c}. \lipsum[3]
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
\caption{Some clever caption\label{c}}
\end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on paracol.  It aligns the bottom of the figure to the insertion point.  Centering would be trickier.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\setcolumnwidth{0.6\textwidth}% last column uses what is left

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{insertfigure}{\switchcolumn[1]\null\vfill% align bottom to insertion point
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}% no floating
\def\@captype{figure}}{\end{minipage}\switchcolumn[0]*}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\section{Lore ipsum}
\lipsum*[2] (See figure \ref{a}).
\begin{insertfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Some clever caption\label{a}}
\end{insertfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Na dui ligula (figure \ref{b})}
\begin{insertfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Some clever caption\label{b}}
\end{insertfigure}
See figure \ref{c}. \lipsum[3]
\begin{insertfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
\caption{Some clever caption\label{c}}
\end{insertfigure}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]