# Placing images and text in separate parallel columns

Tags: graphics, two-column, multicol, layout

I feel like there should be quite a simple answer to this (apologies if so), but have been looking for a while and can't find one. I am trying to format a latex document to match the layout pictured below (e.g. a column containing images parallel to the related text).

This is for a ~100 page document with many images, so I am looking for a solution that's not just hard-coding each image in place, and one that doesn't just involve listing all the images at the end and hoping they match the position of the text. (e.g. one way to do this would be to use something like `tabular` in `beamer`, but I'm hoping that's not the best solution)

Thanks so much!

[image: desired output]

Comment: You might be interested in [two column document so in the first i have text and in the second pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133296/134144)

Comment: oh yeah wow thanks guys, that's exactly what I'm looking for! The title of the linked article makes it a bit tough to find: should I leave this up but mark as duplicate?

Comment: @AgnesCameron: Marking your question as a duplicate is a good idea as it might also help others find the answer. (I like the title you chose for your question.)

Comment: You can also use paracol, although you can only synchronize them between paragraphs.