# Define a custom floating environment in page margins?

Tags: floats, fancyhdr, book-design

I am using `fancyhdr` and `tikz` to create custom sidebars on the left-even and right-odd sides of my pages (for a book, so documentstyle `book`). Is there a way to make a new "floating area" and corresponding "floating environment" within these sidebars, such that I can add small figures into the sidebars and they will flow across page sidebars based on space available, just like they do within the main body of the text when I use `\begin{figure}`? Here is an illustration of I mean:

[image]

Comment: To do this from scratch is, of course, a major piece of work. The idea of TeX.SX is not that some one will do a lot of work for you, so could you please show us what you have tried? Your document class is also likely to be relevant so please give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Do [todonotes](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) or [sidebars](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidebars) do what you want?

Comment: I am not asking someone to create what the document looks like. I was hoping to see if there's a simple answer (I can't find on Google) for how to define a custom float environment that has its own dedicated "pipeline" of figures that get placed elsewhere on the page, than the main pipeline of `\begin{figure}` entries.

Comment: What should the numbering be? Do you intend to use those margin-floats along the normal ones? If I have margin-`figure` will it use the same counter as `figure`? And which has priority?

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz it should be the same as the figure counter in the main body, and should get assigned the figure number the way it appears in the source code/however the figure counter gets assigned.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133296/two-column-document-so-in-the-first-i-have-text-and-in-the-second-pictures

Comment: @JohnKormylo both those solutions put the images directly into the margin with more or less manual placement, they are not really floating as in the sketch of OP.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz - Paracol supports floats (unlike multicol), but without an MWE or specific instructions on how to place them, little more can be done.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I didn't know that `paracol` supports floats. From the sketches in OP's question it appears as if the floats should end up evenly spaced per page. So if only one float is to be output, that float should end up vertically centred. In the answers of the question you linked to both solutions put the content at the same height into the margin.

Answer (score 3):

The following provides some rudimentary support for `marginfloat`s (and `marginfigure` and `margintable`). You can't use `\marginpar` with them (well you can, but don't expect it to work correctly).

Also if you use a normal float with them I can't guarantee that their numbering will be correct (I didn't test that, thoroughly. A quick test with a single `figure` suggests that the numbering is indeed correct, but somehow the margin floats page-break too early).

I let `eso-pic` do the output-routine hacking, which uses `atbegshi`, mostly for its aid in placement using `\AtTextUpperLeft`

**EDIT:** There was a missing `\fi` that should've matched `\ifhmode` (now added), also I've added the length `\marginfloat@sep` which controls the minimum distance between two `marginfloat`s. Also I've switched to using `\vtop to \textheight` instead of `\vbox to \textheight`, so that `\ht\marginfloat@ins\z@` is no longer necessary.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{showframe} % only to show that the placement is roughly correct

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\marginfloat@handle}
\newinsert\marginfloat@ins
\count\marginfloat@ins\z@
\skip\marginfloat@ins\z@
\dimen\marginfloat@ins\textheight
\newlength\marginfloat@sep
\marginfloat@sep2ex
\newenvironment{marginfloat}[1]
  {%
    \def\@captype{#1}%
    \ifhmode\@bsphack\fi
    \insert\marginfloat@ins\bgroup
      \penalty100
      \vbox\bgroup
        \hsize=\marginparwidth
        \linewidth=\hsize
        \@afterheading
        \@afterindentfalse
  }%
  {%
      \egroup
      \vfill
      \vskip\marginfloat@sep
    \egroup
    \@Esphack
  }
\newenvironment{marginfigure}{\marginfloat{figure}}{\endmarginfloat}
\newenvironment{margintable}{\marginfloat{table}}{\endmarginfloat}

\newcommand*\marginfloat@handle
  {%
    \setbox\marginfloat@ins\vtop to \textheight
      {\null\vfill\unvbox\marginfloat@ins\vskip-\marginfloat@sep}%
    \if@twoside
      \ifodd\c@page
        \AtTextUpperLeft
          {%
            \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax},0)
              {\box\marginfloat@ins}%
          }%
      \else
        \AtTextUpperLeft
          {%
            \put(\LenToUnit{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax},0)
              {\box\marginfloat@ins}%
          }%
      \fi
    \else
      \AtTextUpperLeft
        {%
          \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax},0)
            {\box\marginfloat@ins}%
        }%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments} % dummy content

\begin{document}
\blindduck[1-4]
\begin{marginfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{a duck}
\end{marginfigure}
\blindduck[1]
\begin{marginfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{another duck}
\end{marginfigure}
\begin{marginfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{another duck}
\end{marginfigure}
\begin{marginfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{another duck}
\end{marginfigure}
\begin{marginfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{another duck}
\end{marginfigure}
\begin{marginfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{another duck}
\end{marginfigure}
\blindduck[1-4]
\begin{marginfigure}
  This is even more text.
\end{marginfigure}
\blindduck[5]
\begin{marginfigure}
  This is even more text that is really long.
\end{marginfigure}
\clearpage
\begin{marginfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{yet another duck}
\end{marginfigure}
\blindduck[full]
\end{document}
```

The first page of that document:

[image]