# Simple example of using \newinsert and friends?

Tags: floats, footnotes, layout

I'm trying to learn how `\newinsert` and its related macros work for inserting things like footnotes. I've been looking through `latex.ltx` and some other classes which use custom inserts (like `memoir.cls`). But they are a bit complex for me.

What's in my mind is something like `\sidefootnote` from `memoir.cls`, which uses this mechanism. It's just that `memoir.cls` is not quite minimal enough for me to follow what is going on.

I know that this will require adjusting the `\output` routine. Footnotes are output using something like this:

```
\ifvoid\footins\else
  \unvbox\footins
\fi
```

But I can't get anything to output anywhere with something similar and `\myins`.

Can someone provide a simple example for me using the following template?

For now, assume that the document is single column and the inserted text should flow from one page to the next like footnotes do.

Footnotes are output at the bottom of the page. I'd like `\myins` to be output somewhere else on the page, e.g., a in side margin starting at the top of the main text.

The `tikz` box is just to show where the inserted text should end up.

(I wasn't sure how to tag this question, so please adjust as necessary.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin]{babel} % better hyphenation for Lorem ipsum
\usepackage{microtype} % avoid overfull \hbox

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz} % for sample box
\usepackage[a5paper, top=2cm, left=6.85cm, width=6cm, height=15cm]{geometry}

\newinsert\myins

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\insert\myins{\lipsum[2]}

% This is where I want the insert to appear
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0pt]
  \node[draw, anchor=north west, text width=3cm, text depth=15cm,
    font=\small, minimum width=3.2cm, minimum height=15.2cm]
    at ([xshift=1.9cm, yshift=-1.9cm]current page.north west)
    {\lipsum[2]};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I believe this [answer of Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526349/73317) comes close (“margin floats”). I assume you've read chapter 15 of the TeXbook until the very end of the last paragraph, as well as chapter 23 on `\output` routines? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I want to do something similar to footnotes and noticed that they used `\insert`. But that is my only reason.

Comment: You could produce the example shown with a standard `\marginpar` if you need something different to that can you give more information as to what is needed?

Comment: @frougon, my copy of the TeX Book isn't accessible at the moment. I'll take a look at Skillmon's answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'm interested in both how to position the float and how it flows when there is more content than will fit on the page. The question isn't so much about how to achieve an outcome, but how to understand a mechanism.

Comment: @frougon hmm or at least uses an existing output routine hack, but OK I'll clean up my comments a bit. However the question still remains why `\marginpar` is not the answer here.

Comment: Yes Skillmon's answer looks like it's trying to do something similar to what I want. I will look at it more closely. I know that using `\insert` involves adjusting the `\output` routine. @DavidCarlisle, doesn't `\marginpar` might do what I want, but doesn't it attempt to line text up with where it is inserted in the main text? I want more like side footnotes.

Comment: @DavidPurton that's why I have been pushing you to clarify your question. Just looking at the image it is not clear if the box is in the margin or a cutout like wrapfig.  If you run the example the tikz puts it in the margin but the question doesn't give any indication on what you want. In particular why isn't the code in the question the answer, or why isn't \marginpar the answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I added a comment about `\sidefootnote` from `memoir.cls`. Does that help?

Comment: @DavidPurton possibly it would if I new memoir better:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I believe the main problem with `\marginpar` here is that David Purton wants the side text to start at the top of the page, rather than starting vertically where `\marginpar` would be used.

Comment: @frougon I guess so, but demonstrating that fact with no words in the question  and an image where  the "top of page" and "where used" are the same place, doesn't make the question as clear as it could be....

Comment: @frougon, yes! You win today's guess what is in my mind prize!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the problem with this (and many unclear questions) is that the authors don't have your understanding of TeX's internals. So we can't always write a clear question and keep it minimal. It's easy to write a clear question like "How do I make something *look* like this. It's harder to ask a clear question about how something is working in `latex.ltx` when there are *many* unclear aspects (to me) of what is going on.

Comment: @DavidPurton yes I'm not trying to criticise, just push the question to be clearer, because honestly without this discussion in comments (which the site tries to suppress) I wouldn't have made the right guess for the desired behaviour here.

Comment: @frougon, Skillmon's answer does not flow the content on the the next page like a footnote does if it doesn't fit.

Comment: @DavidPurton I believe it does—if properly adapted, i.e.: you'll probably want to get rid of the `\vbox` in the `marginfloat` environment. What kind of separation do you want between two side notes?

Comment: I think that what you are after is `memoir` s `\sidebar` command. The text in the margin starts at the top of the page and can continue on for as many pages as necessary. The code is documented in `memoir.dtx` which should be on your system just as `memoir.cls` is. The code gets more complicated if you need to control which margin is used, so it is not as "simple" as footnotes. I can no longer really understand what I did many years ago. GOM

Comment: @DavidPurton, ask what you want to do, not how to do it with a particular tool. There might be a simpler, cleaner way to get where you want to go.

Comment: @vonbrand, I already know how to achieve the outcome by using the `memoir` document class. If I'd asked "how does the `memoir` `\sidebar` feature work?", the question would have been closed as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What follows is an adaptation of [an answer by @Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526349/73317) to do something like what you want (in the absence of enough information, I had to take decisions: I added a `sidenote` counter and numbered the side notes; they are vertically stacked, separated by a skip of at most 1 point.

As you can see, text does flow from one page to the next (in particular, the insertions can be split). My example below shows a word in a side note that is hyphenated between two pages.

There is one known problem (as far as I understand it, Skillmon's answer has exactly the same). My understanding of this problem is as follows: as the LaTeX `\output` routine is not aware of this new class of floats, it doesn't automatically flush the queue of such floats that haven't found a place on any page yet, neither when doing `\clearpage`, nor at the end of the document—where `\end{document}` precisely issues a `\clearpage` in order to output dangling floats. That is why, in this example,  I have to create an otherwise empty page with `\clearpage\mbox{}` at the end of the document. Without it, the insertions that haven't been shipped out yet remain in TeX's memory, never to appear on a page.

According to the TeXbook p. 125, the total number of such “dangling” insertions (for all float classes) appears in `\insertpenalties` during an `\output` routine. So, this should be fixable... by hacking the LaTeX `\output` routine, which is notoriously hairy. As I haven't studied it (the LaTeX `\output` routine), consider this code as a proof of concept.

```latex
% Adapted from Skillmon's answer: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526349/73317>
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe} % only to show that the placement is roughly correct
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{sidenote}

\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\sidenote@handle}
\newinsert\sidenote@ins
\count\sidenote@ins\z@
\skip\sidenote@ins\z@
\dimen\sidenote@ins\textheight

\newenvironment{sidenote}
  {%
    \ifmmode\else\@bsphack\fi
    \insert\sidenote@ins\bgroup
      \hsize=\marginparwidth
      \linewidth=\hsize
      \@afterheading\@afterindentfalse
      \refstepcounter{sidenote}%
      \normalfont\small \strut \textsuperscript{\thesidenote}%
      \ignorespaces
  }%
  {%
      \unskip
      \strut\par
      \vskip \z@ \@plus 1pt     % small amount of stretchability between notes
    \egroup
    \@Esphack
    \ignorespacesafterend       % \@ignoretrue in \@Esphack isn't \global
  }

\newcommand*\sidenote@handle
  {%
    \setbox\sidenote@ins\vbox to \textheight
      {% Prevent color from bleeding outside the side margin (it will not
       % continue to the next page, even if that was desired).
        \color@vbox\normalcolor
        \vbox to \textheight
          {%
            \unvbox\sidenote@ins \unskip
            \lastbox % set \prevdepth from the last box
            % Let descenders from the last line of the side box descend. In
            % this example, this won't be visible unless you insert an
            % infinitely stretchable skip somewhere in the side note material.
            % Indeed, the \vskip \z@ \@plus 0.0001fil always wins against the
            % \vskip \z@ \@plus 1pt we insert between footnotes.
            \ifdim\prevdepth>\z@
              \vskip -\ifdim \prevdepth>\maxdepth \maxdepth \else \prevdepth \fi
            \fi
            % Fill the remaining space, but let fill and filll “crush” that.
            \vskip \z@ \@plus 0.0001fil
          }%
        \color@endbox
      }%
    \if@twoside
      \ifodd\c@page
        \AtTextLowerLeft
          {%
            \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax},0)
              {\box\sidenote@ins}%
          }%
      \else
        \AtTextLowerLeft
          {%
            \put(\LenToUnit{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax},0)
              {\box\sidenote@ins}%
          }%
      \fi
    \else
      \AtTextLowerLeftr
        {%
          \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax},0)
            {\box\sidenote@ins}%
        }%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{sidenote}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{sidenote}

\begin{sidenote}
  \lipsum[3-4] YYY
\end{sidenote}

\lipsum[3-5] XXX
\clearpage\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

My updated code allows descenders at the bottom of side notes to go below the bottom line of the side box, as expected. It is simply not visible in the previous example, because there isn't any skip in the provided side note material that can counteract the `\vskip \z@ \@plus 0.0001fil` used to fill side note boxes in `\raggedbottom` style. But if you comment out this skip (and add `\par\vspace*{\fill}` at the end of the last side note so that it gets filled in `\raggedbottom` style) and provide enough stretchability in the side note material, you'll see the descenders descend:

[image]

Of course, appropriate `\marginparwidth`, possibly font changes, `\sloppy` or whatever measures will probably be necessary in real-world applications to let TeX pack the contents in the margin in a decent way (the example has many overfull `\hbox`es due to the short lines in the side margin). You can set such parameters at the place where I used `\small`. This is also where the `sidenote` counter is printed, in case you want to change or remove this numbering of the notes.

Color isn't really supported. I mean, the `\insert` mechanism can break the vertical material where it wants, so this will prevent color from legally flowing from one side box to the next. But my updated code attempts to avoid the nastiest possible problems (it prevents color from bleeding after a side box).

Comment: I updated the code a little bit. If you find it difficult to understand, start with the first revision, then move to the current code. :-) (I've commented most additions, though.) Regarding colors, I believe LaTeX has similar limitations in footnotes (maybe LuaTeX can do better with its new color mechanism).

Comment: This is good! And certainly breaks things down. There's still plenty for me to get my head around. I like this paragraph on page 123 of the TeXBook: "You might want to review the page-breaking algorithm explained at the beginning of this chapter, before reading further. On the other hand, maybe you don’t really want to read the rest of this chapter at all, ever."

Comment: Yes, this end of chapter is... interesting. Don't forget to look at the TeXbook erratum while you're at it: there is a little correction concerning how split insertions are reported, IIRC.