# How to put a table in marginpar?

Tags: tables, marginpar

I would like to add a placement option "m" to the regular table environment to put small tables in the outer margin of the document.

I can achieve it "by hand" using the following code:

```
\marginpar{%
\begin{tabularx}{\marginparwidth}{X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
    \hline%
    Dipôle & Impédance complexe \\%
    \hline%
    Conducteur ohmique & $R$ \\%
    Condensateur & $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\i \cdot C \cdot \omega}}$ \\%
    Bobine & $\i \cdot L \cdot \omega$ \\%
    \hline%
\end{tabularx}%
\captionof{table}{Impédances complexes de quelques dipôles.}%
\label{tbl:impedances}%
}%
```

but it does not work anymore when I try to transpose that in a more "automated" way.

I tried (*.sty file):

```
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\def\mparenvironment#1\end{\marginpar{\centering #1}\end}
\newboolean{mparend}%
\renewenvironment{table}[1][ht]%
    {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{m}}{\setboolean{mparend}{true}}{\setboolean{mparend}{false}}%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{mparend}}{%
            \let\caption\maketablemparcaption%
            \mparenvironment%
        }{%
            \let\@makecaption\@makefloatcaption%
            \@float{table}[#1]%
        }%
    }{%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{mparend}}{%
            %
        }{%
            \end@float%
        }%
    }%
```

and (*.tex file):

```
\begin{table}[m]%
    \begin{tabularx}{\marginparwidth}{X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
        \hline%
        Dipôle & Impédance complexe \\%
        \hline%
        Conducteur ohmique & $R$ \\%
        Condensateur & $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\i \cdot C \cdot \omega}}$ \\%
        Bobine & $\i \cdot L \cdot \omega$ \\%
        \hline%
    \end{tabularx}%
    \caption{Impédances complexes de quelques dipôles.}%
    \label{tbl:impedances}%
\end{table}%
```

I get the following errors:

```
! Argument of \TX@get@body has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.314   \end
           {tabularx}

! Paragraph ended before \TX@get@body was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.314   \end
           {tabularx}

! You can't use `\vadjust' in internal vertical mode.
\sf@end@float ...ty \@floatpenalty \else \vadjust 
                                                  {\penalty -\@Miv \vbox {}\...
l.314   \end
           {tabularx}

! LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 305 ended by \end{tabularx}.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.317 \end{table}

! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

If I replace the tabular(x) environment by some text or picture, it works perfectly... Of course, it also works if I use a regular placement option (e.g. "ht").

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really what you want, but at least related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526349/117050

Comment: You might also look at tuftbook, although you will have to put up with a lot of other changes.  Technically, \marginpar IS a float, so you are trying to put a float inside another float.

Comment: The marginnotes package uses a tikz overlay instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually, I don't put a float inside another float since what I put in marginpar is tabular only, not the whole "table" environment - it's not anymore a float. Another way to formulate my question is: what is different between the two versions I propose? (when I directly encapsulate the tabular with \marginpar, it works as I want...)