# Format a two column book with text on one side and images on the other

Tags: two-column, books, book-design

I would like to know how to format an entire book in this way, with one column for text and the other for figures. I have seen solutions to do this with mini-sections but is there a simple way to do this for the whole book ?

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at the `tufte` classes, or the `sidenotes` package and its class `caesar` book class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could just use `\marginpar` to put the figures as annotations in the margins.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry for the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help, I found the answer in another [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78413/199781), here is what it looks like. This way of doing it make the figures start at the top of the page and work their way downwards, rather than aligning them with the text where the marginal note appears.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\newflowframe{0.65\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[main]
\newdynamicframe{0.3\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.7\textwidth}{0pt}[sidepanel]

% For two-sided documents, swap locations on odd pages

\setflowframe*{main}{evenx=0.35\textwidth}
\setdynamicframe*{sidepanel}{clear,evenx=0pt}

\newcommand{\sidefigure}[1]{%
\appenddynamiccontents*{sidepanel}{%
 \begin{staticfigure}
  \centering
  #1%
 \end{staticfigure}
 \vspace{\baselineskip}%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\sidefigure{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test-image}
\caption{Sample Figure}
\label{fig:sample1}
}

\lipsum[2]

\sidefigure{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test-image}
\caption{Another Sample Figure}
\label{fig:sample2}
}

\lipsum[3-5]

\sidefigure{%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test-image}
\caption{A Third Sample Figure}
\label{fig:sample3}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @siracusa Sorry, I edited the post to include the code and a brief explanation of what it does.