Position the text on the left and the images on the right for the entire document
How can I do the following formatting for the entire document?
That's what I expect to see:

I tried to make it in the form of a minipage/table, but the text and pictures are not located on the same level. And I didn't understand how to limit table/minipage vertically (to the bottom margin of the page).
My preamble:
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}

\usepackage{tempora} % Times New Roman

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,bottom=15mm,left=20mm,right=15mm}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg}

\usepackage{ctable} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=off, labelsep=endash}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\textsc{-}} 
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Рисунок},labelsep=endash,font=small}


As said to your question on main meta, maybe use a really wide right margin and place the figures in the margin...

Welcome. // This seems to be a frame layout as you find e.g. in newspapers, journals and other printed matter. If so, what you want is to define different frames and control flow from (some) frame to some other frames. If so, have a look at Nicola Talbots excellent package flowfram at https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram . However, using it may requires some sound LaTeX experience beforehand.

related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43941/figures-in-odd-pages-text-in-even-pages-if-no-figures-then-odd-even-pages-i

@MS-SPO Thank you very much! How can I use this package? Should I download and install it? I use TexMaker

I‘ll answer by example. My TeX distribution is MikTex, which I configured to ask me for permission whenever it detects a missing package to install it, following texmf standard. With this I can just type, e.g. \usepackage{flowfram} in my code, e.g. via editor TexMKaker, and compile. // flowfram is best tried out, with its User manual and the FAQs open, see aboves link. If you search for flowfram here, as always, many questions will be „too much“, but a few just give you the right clue. Start simple, via the User guide, refine towards your goal. // Evaluate Davids simpler solution, too.

The answers to this question might be interesting for you, showing alternatives and a flowfram approach by N.T. : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71508/objective-to-separate-text-column-from-figures-column-in-every-page/78413#78413

As I read it, your question has two components:

sth. like a template style for the whole document
a/the grid problem

For the first one the comments mention several approaches, including your own one, minipages. Let's focus now on the second one, the broken baselines:

I tried to make it in the form of a minipage/table, but the text and
pictures are not located on the same level.

So let's have a look at Latex and the grid, Background, a Demo and a Possible manual solution, below.
LaTeX and the grid
If you come from Desktop Publishing (DTP), very often you can set a grid to keep text baselines in-sync across pages. Many LaTeX users struggle with that, if you search some keywords here:

all (or most ?) grid related questions
grid & dtp
grid & latex

Background
As you may know, LaTeX is built around TeX. TeX was developed in the 1970s-1980s by D. Knuth, who was first a mathematician, until he became professor in informatics. Bothered by the then bad quality of photolithography he created TeX, to create beautiful books, especially with mathematics inside.
So starting with plain ASCII text, TeX, i.e. people using TeX, adds a variety of commands to mimick typesetting, just like Gutenberg did with metal letters. A few things are relevant wrt your question:

TeX abstracts each letter (and other thingies) into boxes (their outlines for simplicity)
it assembles such boxes horizontally to form lines
and such lines vertically to form pages (regardless of paper sizes)
it judges several badnesses to ensure a kind a beauty per page
once a page is done, it sends it to its output routine, and continues, until all input was processed

In achieving "beauty" TeX, hence also LaTeX, uses degree of freedoms, e.g. varying horizontal and vertical spaces etc., best invisibly. (See his "The Texbook" for details.)
Conceptually, besides dealing with orphants and widows, there is no such concept as far as I know about a grid across pages, to match multi-page baselines. La/TeX just focusses on filling a page "nicely" at a time.
Demo
To demonstrate this effect I create 2 pages in twocolumn style below. As you can see:

both columns are baseline-aligned for the first page
start to be aligned on the second, but drift once a "mismatching" object is inserted vertically, like an image with a "bad" height
this is what we also see in your screenshot, comparing left text and right captions


\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}



% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \twocolumn
 
 % ~~~ happens to fit on first page ~~~~~~~~~~
 \lipsum[1-5]
 
 % ~~~ (almost) starting at the second page ~~~
 \lipsum[1]
 
    % ~~~ disturbing "the grid" ~~~~~~~
    \includegraphics[height=33pt]{example-image}
 
 \lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}

Possible manual solution
The grid-problem arises once you insert objects (image, caption etc.) which somehow break the baselines. So what you could do manually, is things like:

adjusting image heights (e.g. with 30 pt it was fine)
deliberately insert vertical space, like (untested) \vspace{9pt}
etc.

WARNINGS:

when writing or changing text, you can't know in advance, where a page starts, i.e. which content goes where (floats increase this unknown)
La/TeX just does its best page-by-page
results will depend on various layout related things, like font sizes, margins etc.

So either accept this pecularity of La/TeX, or do those manual alignments as the very last step, once you freeze your content.
BTW, if you follow some links from the beginning, some claim to have an approach for a grid.
